# Setting up VPS with MySQL PHP and Nginx

Tags: vps

Hi I have been following this guide to set up a VPS on Linode:
http://themesforge.com/featured/high-performance-wordpress-part-3/

Everything works well, however the domains I have set up just give me the Nginx welcome screen and don't bring up the stuff from their own folder. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works well, however the domains I have set up just give me the Nginx welcome screen and don't bring up the stuff from their own folder. What might I be doing wrong?

Nginx (and other modern http servers) can host multiple sites on one IP address using the HTTP HOST header, which tells the server which of the sites the browser wishes delivered to it.

Virtual hosts therefore attempt to match this host header to one of the virtual hosts they have. If this cannot be achieved, nginx serves the content from its default site, whichever that is

This is, I suspect what is happening here. As such, I would:

- Check your virtual host `server_name` [directives](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) match what you're expecting to use.
- Ensure you're accessing the site through the dns you expect. For example, my host give me a DNS entry like this: `myaccount1.vps.myhost.net`. Going to there triggers my default handler, because that's the host, whereas `http://www.ninefingersisawesome.com` goes to the right place.

Comment: damn, that's not a real domain :(